# Debian 7 - iptables 'filter' not supported?

Tags: debian, iptables

Am attempting to forward/ masquerade connections from WLAN0 to ETH0 as follows:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

The first command works.

The second command responds with: `iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.`

If I remove the `-m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED` portion of the command it is accepted.

I've looked at kernel modules using **lsmod | grep ip** and 'ip_tables' is present. I'm missing something obvious here. Suggestions?

Debian 7 (armv7l)

Comment: What if you do `modprobe xt_state`? See [this](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=xt_state&mode=filename&suite=stable&arch=armhf).

Comment: "module not found" - doesn't appear to be compiled in. The file `/lib/xtables/libxt_state.so` is available though. No '.ko' file found.

Comment: What's your kernel version? (`uname -v` or -- better -- `uname -a`)?

Comment: ~# uname -a
Linux odroid-01 3.8.13.3 #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Jun 22 00:52:21 BRT 2013 armv7l GNU/Linux

Comment: I then wonder where did you get that kernel from. Debian 7 ("Wheezy") lists [these kernels](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=xt_state.ko&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=armhf) for "ARM hardfloat" (`armhf`) arch. Even if we [consider backports](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=wheezy-backports&arch=armhf&mode=path&searchon=contents&keywords=xt_state.ko), that's `3.16.x`, not `3.8.x`. I'm afraid you might have gotten some custom-compiled kernel which misses the stuff you want.

Comment: Is the kernel provided by the [`odroid` project](http://odroid.us) (as your kernel version string suggests)? Then try grepping the `/boot/config-<your-kernel-version>` file for the word `CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_STATE` -- it should be 1) not commented out, 2) assigned either "y" or "m" ("yes" vs "module") value, 3) not assigned the "n" ("no") value.

Comment: Yeah - that's starting to look more like it. There are other issues with this build as well. *sigh*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18736/discussion-between-kostix-and-ethrbunny).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `state` Netfilter module is implemented using the kernel module named `xt_state`, so if an attempt to use it fails right away, it's possible to try doing

```
# modprobe xt_state
```

If that fails, the kernel most probably is compiled with the support for advanced Netfilter features disabled.

To verify it, one can search `/boot/config-<your-kernel-version>` file for the word `CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_STATE` which should be

1. not commented out,
2. assigned a value which is either "y" or "m" ("yes" vs "module"),
3. not assigned the "n" value ("no").

---

Further investigation with the OP showed that they have a kernel supplied by the [`odroid`](http://odroid.us) installed, not a stock Debian Wheezy kernel for the `armhf` architecture.

Comment: For the record - should say 'odroid'